# how to autoplay the video in an ember app

Tags: ember.js

I have added video to my ember app using videojs plugin .. i have done 
bower install videojs-youtube and npm install videojs-youtube in my app.
I am showing the video as a pop up but video is not autoplayed . how to auto play the video using an ember app..

HTML:

```
<video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    width="640" height="264"
    data-setup='{"techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}], "youtube": { "iv_load_policy": 1 } }'
>
</video>

<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true" {{action 'play'}}></i>
```

JavaScript:

```
play() {
  $('#video').modal('show');
  $("#vid1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
},
```

Comment: Please format your code by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably only need one. If it's a front-end plugin dependency you are likely better off using bower since it'll install with a reliable folder structure you can use.

For the external bower plugin to be included make sure you include it in your application's `ember-cli-build.js` ([instructions](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#javascript-assets)).

The action you have setup looks good, but since you are relying on this being on the jQuery object you should scope it to the component's context. In the play action use `this.$()`, ie: `this.$('#video')`

Lastly, the ember ecosystem is rich with ember-y wrappers to avoid this type of manual setup of existing plugins. This [ember-addon](https://github.com/IvyApp/ivy-videojs) might do what you are a looking for with a lot less setup and documentation in the context of ember. Shop around for other addons at [Ember Observer](https://emberobserver.com/).